# Remotly logging into Managebac

Tags: php, curl

First of all, I want to make clear that I've tried many different ways and read quite a lot of articles about this, but none worked completely.

I've got to the point, where I successfully get the cookies by cURL, but when I try to actually use them, it simply fails and says that I'm being redirected.

The point, where I want to get, is that I just want to log in, retrieve the data from my profile and then do stuff with it...

Here's where I am right now (it just saves the correct cookies, but doesn't return back MY post-login page):

```
$url="https://myschool.managebac.com/sessions/";

$postdata = "login=myname@myschool.com&password=password&commit=Sign-in&remember_me=1";

$cr = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);  
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');   
$header = curl_exec($cr); 
curl_close($cr); 

$cr2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cr2, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://myschool.managebac.com/');
curl_setopt($cr2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($cr2, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($cr2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($cr2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt'); 
$result = curl_exec($cr2);
curl_close($cr2);
```

I hope that there actually is a possible way, because Managebac is not that used application (mainly for IB students), but it would help me a great deal if I got this working.

I'm glad for every and each answer.

Comment: Just as a comment, you can use an array of PHP keys=>values as your POST data, and cURL will handle it.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but most of the code is actually copied from somewhere and just changed few things. After the app will work, I will organize it much better.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've somehow managed to do it.

Right now, it gets the wanted information and does everything fine.

If someone would want the code, here it is:

```
$url="https://myschool.managebac.com/sessions";
$postdata = "login=mylogin&password=mypassword&commit=Sign-in&remember_me=1";

$cr_curlopt = array(CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
                    CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
                    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postdata,
                    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookie.txt');

$cr = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($cr, $cr_curlopt);
$header = curl_exec($cr);

curl_close($cr); 

$cr2_curlopt = array(CURLOPT_URL => "http://myschool.managebac.com",
                    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
                    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookie.txt');

$cr2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($cr2, $cr2_curlopt);
$result = curl_exec($cr2);
curl_close($cr2);

print $result;
```

Btw, I have no idea why would it actually help, but it started working after I changed the curlopt adding from seperate strings to one array. (thanks DanRedux)

Comment: This doesn't really work anymore. Do you know of any workaround?

Comment: I have eventually given up on the idea after Managebac released their (decent but not perfect) app and I'm done with IB, so I can't even test it anymore, I'm afraid. But I would guess that it should work fairly similarly even now - login, get the cookies, store them, use them for access. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: After months of trying, I've finally managed to login. ManageBac redirects to like 3 different URLs and you have to cURL them one by one to login... :) Here's the source: https://github.com/FoxInFlame/Unofficial-ManageBacAPI/blob/master/api/0.1/authenticate_base.php

Comment: Looks great (and unnecessarily complicated from the side of Managebac), thanks for sharing :)!